# AsanaConnect oAuth Redirect URL with custom scheme

Tags: ios, asana

The account settings page for registering an app accepts just valid http:// url schemes. We would require a custom url scheme in order to redirect back to our iOS app. Is there currently a way to provide a custom url scheme or if not, would it be possible to allow custom URL schemes from your side?

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana.) We agree those would be useful. There is currently no way to use non-http schemes but we will look into adding them soon. Stay tuned!

Comment: "Useful" is an understatement :-). Without a custom scheme it's not possible to use Asana Connect with Android apps, because any http url would be redirected in the browser as is, instead of redirecting to the app. Accepting non-http schemes in the "register app" settings would be the preferred way to fix that but allowing a redirect url that's different from the one in the settings (twitter does that), would also work.

Comment: Just noticed this, and it's huge. I'm not writing a mobile app, but a desktop app with a WebView to do the OAuth authentication. I don't have a valid redirect_uri within a desktop app, so anything other than a valid HTTP URI would work to allow me to grab the token out of the hash.

Comment: Or even having something like Salesforce has with a "success" url after login that could be my redirect_uri... https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success

Comment: We still don't support non-http schemes (sorry, this hasn't been high on our priority list) but we DO support the standard "native" URIs for redirect: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto`. These will actually redirect to an Asana-hosted page which puts the code in the window title for the hosting app to pull out. The first one displays a code for the user to copy, while the latter expects the app to auto-close the window.